# Create incremental value with restart with condition within ID

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

so I have a data of 2 fields, ID and Timestamp

```
ID Time
1 12
1 15
1 16
2 12
2 11
```

And i want to increment if the difference between time and previous time is inferior to 2 for example within the same ID, unless stay at the same value and restart at 1 when ID is different.

Desired output:

```
ID Time ID_SESSION
1 12 1
1 15 1
1 16 2
2 12 1
2 11 1
```

It would be needed in dplyr/sparklyr for spark implementation with R/

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner using base R,

```
with(df, ave(Time, ID, FUN = function(i)cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(i) <= 2))))
#[1] 1 1 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

May be we need

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(ID_SESSION = (lag(c(FALSE, diff(Time) > 2), default= FALSE)) + 1)
```

---

Or in a one-liner with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, ID_SESSION := shift(c(FALSE, diff(Time) > 2), fill = FALSE) + 1, ID]
df1
#   ID Time ID_SESSION
#1:  1   12          1
#2:  1   15          1
#3:  1   16          2
#4:  2   12          1
#5:  2   11          1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Time = c(12L, 15L, 
16L, 12L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hello, i tried your dplyr solution and had the following error: Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function lag(named_struct(col1, FALSE, col2, diff(`TIMESTAMP`) > 1800.0), 1, false) requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT lag(named_struct(col1, FALSE, col2, diff(`TIMESTAMP`) > 1800.0), 1, false)(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table;

Comment: Time = TIMESTAMP from my example, basically the same thing

Comment: @josef_joestarr  Are you using the same example data in my example as I don't get an error

Comment: tbl(sc,'main_view_ui') %>%
  group_by(GA_ID) %>% arrange(GA_ID, TIMESTAMP) %>%
  mutate(ID_SESSION = (lag(c(FALSE, diff(TIMESTAMP) > 1800), default= FALSE)) + 1)

Comment: Yes it's just a float and ID is text

Comment: Yes i know but since im not interested into turning in to datetime just  a double, i had the following error that doesn't seem correlated to the type:  Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'lag(named_struct('col1', 'FALSE', 'col2', 'diff(`TIMESTAMP`) > 1800.0'), 1, false)' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires (struct<col1:string,col2:string> or null) type, however, 'false' is of boolean type.; line 1 pos 519;